# Links don't work when Z-index is changed

Tags: html, css

Here is my work I have done so far: [Social Network](https://codepen.io/imak08/pen/gKYPma)

If in the class `.cover-profile` I change the value of `z-index` then the link stop working for the class .navigation.

I have fixed the navbar at the top and want other things to be behind the navbar when scrolling.

Comment: Please check this page to improve your chances of getting an answer :[ask]

Comment: Did you get an error message telling you that you couldn't link to codepen without including the code *in the question itself*? The wasn't a suggestion to claim that the URL to Codepen is your source code! You need to provide an [mcve] **in the quesiton itself**. Stackoverflow even supports embedded [live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

try to use as
.navbar {
 z-index: 2;
}
.cover-profile {
 z-index: 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

What is .cover-profile? 
I delete z-index from .cover-profile, and add z-index to navbar

```
.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #eb3b5a;
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1;
}
```

You can check it here
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKbVaE

Answer (score 0):

That's because you place the whole `.cover-profile` class behind the `<body>` of your page. That's why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKbVgr

Issue is here `.cover-profile { z-index: -1; }`

Regarding the z-index property, it specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

In this case `"cover-profile"` has a z-index of -1, it will be placed behind your `body`.